# Wired Xbox One Controller Shows in lsusb but stops detecting input in steam sometimes

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, steam

After a reboot, my wired controller works with steam. There is a light on the controller that is on whenever this is working. Sometimes, however, the light randomly turns off and then input stops working in my games. This also happens if a re-plugin the controller without rebooting. The device still shows up in lsusb at this point. If I run a usbreset on it, the light turns back on and then it begins to work again. I have a helper script that will search for the device and reset it if I need to, however, it's inconvenient to alt+tab to run it.

Was hoping to automate it was some sort of systemd task. I can't figure out how to programmatically tell when it's in this state, though. I tried lsusb --verbose but the output is the same whether or not the input is being detected.The controller also doesn't show up in xinput. I'm not sure where else I could check so looking for some ideas on how I may be able to tell if input is being detected from a usb device using a script. I can take care of the rest from there. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I can use `jstest` to achieve what I want. Ended up making a script like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
function xboxControllerReset() {
    device_id="$(docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script -v /home/<me>/.local/bin:/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp python-runner python getLsUsbDeviceIdForXboxController.py)"
    echo "Resetting device with ID: $device_id"
    sudo usbreset "$device_id"
}

function detectControllerReset() {
  jstest --event /dev/input/js0 || sleep 1 && xboxControllerReset && sleep 1 && detectControllerReset
}

detectControllerReset
```

When my controller goes inactive, it throws a no device found error in jstest. I use `||` to catch this error, reset the `deviceId`, and then call this script again to start the `jstest` feed. I get roughly a second of downtime. I'm sure this could be optimized to not need the one second sleep time, but I don't need this for my purposes.